# Should NGINX resolve proxy_pass from localhost?

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I'm newbie in nginx, please help.

Here is my simple config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name kama.com.local;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:7565;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;  # Pass real IP address to node
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

It resolves my service from outside as expected, so nginx resolves `kama.com.local` to `localhost:7565`. But if local service tries to resolve `kama.com.local` nginx do not resolve anything. Simple test `ping kama.com.local` on nginx machine resolves not found.

Should nginx act as DNS from it's localhost, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: nginx is a web server, not a DNS server.

Comment: Yes, I guess so. Can you suggest the best practice to automaticaly add DNS records according to NGINX configs? Please)